# What is the closest biblatex style to the bibliography requirement of AIMS Press?

Tags: biblatex

This is a sample of their required style.

[image]

[image]

[image]

1. Does this style have a specific name?
2. If not, what are the adaptations for `biblatex` numeric style to match the style shown?

The requirements as I see are as follows

**Journals**

- Author names are a maximum of 3. After this number they use the bibstring `andothers` as et al with a comma before it
- Only the publication year is shown between brackets directly after author names
- The journal name is in italic followed by non-italic volume and pages names as follows

> Journal Name Volume: starting page-ending page.

**Books**

- Between author names and the year, there is a comma

> Serrin J, (1971)

- Book title is italic with edition followed
- When the book has authors for each chapter and a main author. Chapter name is non-italic while main author name is right before main book name
- Publication city, publisher name, and pages are as follows

> New York: Academic Press, 35–75

**Online content**

- Starts with a title followed by comma and year
- Provides the link as

> Available from: link (in monospaced black font)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ciarreta2017modeling,
    title={Modeling and forecasting realized volatility in German--Austrian continuous intraday electricity prices},
    author={Ciarreta, Aitor and Muniain, Peru and Zarraga, Ainhoa},
    journal={Journal of Forecasting},
    volume={36},
    number={6},
    pages={680--690},
    year={2017},
    publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
@inproceedings{bokde2017pattern,
    title={Pattern sequence similarity based techniques for wind speed forecasting},
    author={Bokde, N and Troncoso, A and Asencio-Cort{\'e}s, G and Kulat, K and Mart{\'\i}nez-{\'A}lvarez, F},
    booktitle={Proceedings of the International Work-Conference on Time Series, Granada, Spain},
    volume={2},
    pages={786--794},
    year={2017}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib} 

\begin{document}
    
    \nocite{*}
    
    \newrefcontext[sorting=ydnt]
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    
\end{document}
```